# Telethon - How to serialize a file in a message to sent it later?

Tags: serialization, deserialization, telethon

In my telethon project, I need to receive messages from some private channels, and then store in a database the relevant information of those messages to be sent to different channels at a later date. I can do this for the message itself, whether the message is a reply to another message, etc. My issue is how to do the same with the files if there are any.

I want to send the same messages I receive in channel A to channel B at a later date, so all files must be serialized to store them in a DB. I want to know how I can achieve this, store a string representation on the file and then how to turn that string representation into the file again.

The message object I get from a telethon message has a structure like this:

```
{'_': 'MessageMediaPhoto', 'photo': {'_': 'Photo', 'id': 4938497802787465505, 'access_hash': -1688573292593521174, 'file_reference': "b'\\x04E-jJ\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x04`\\x90[\\xe6\\xc1ES_\\xc5\\xbd\\x1c@\\x0c\\t\\xea\\x9a\\x19F\\xa9\\xb3'", 'date': '2021-05-03 20:11:06+00:00', 'sizes': [{'_': 'PhotoStrippedSize', 'type': 'i', 'bytes': 'b"\\x01(\\x16\\xd1\\xd9\'L\\xb0\\xf7\\xdfY:\\x92/\\xdb1$\\x84\\x1d\\x83\\xd4\\xe7\\xadj\\x15}\\xdc\\x17\\xeb\\xfd\\xf1U\\xe5(\\x97L[\\xefy`\\r\\xdc\\x9e\\xf4\\xd2\\xb8^\\xc6<\\xa1@\\x049$\\xfb\\x1a*\\xec\\xcd\\x1c\\xd1\\xaa\\xb6\\xdd\\xe0\\xf3\\xc6\\xda*\\x94<\\xc1\\xb3[jg9\\x7f\\xfb\\xe4\\xff\\x00\\x85P\\xbd\\x964\\xbb\\xc9\\x07\\xee\\x81\\xd0\\xd6\\x86\\xc8I\\xfb\\xbc\\xfd\\rQ\\xbb\\x8d\\xcd\\xc01\\xc2\\xec\\xa1@\\x07\\xff\\x00\\xd7P4\\xdawE9$\\x8eF\\xc4\\x8b\\xb7\\x1d2\\r\\x15,\\xd1K \\x03\\xcbn9\\xa2\\x9d\\x97q\\xb9\\xbe\\xc6\\x99B$,\\x11s\\x9c\\xf4\\xff\\x00\\xebRM\\x92A\\xe8q\\xda\\x8a(J\\xe47a\\xaa\\xb9\\x18\\xdd\\x8a(\\xa2\\x96\\xda\\x06\\xfa\\x9f"'}, {'_': 'PhotoSize', 'type': 'm', 'location': {'_': 'FileLocationToBeDeprecated', 'volume_id': 806529124, 'local_id': 432736}, 'w': 173, 'h': 320, 'size': 22179}, {'_': 'PhotoSize', 'type': 'x', 'location': {'_': 'FileLocationToBeDeprecated', 'volume_id': 806529124, 'local_id': 432737}, 'w': 432, 'h': 800, 'size': 82795}, {'_': 'PhotoSizeProgressive', 'type': 'y', 'location': {'_': 'FileLocationToBeDeprecated', 'volume_id': 806529124, 'local_id': 432734}, 'w': 518, 'h': 960, 'sizes': [6255, 8444, 59238, 61659, 64084]}], 'dc_id': 1, 'has_stickers': False, 'video_sizes': []}, 'ttl_seconds': None}
```

But I'm asuming I don't need all of this to just send the same image in a different channel

Comment: The only long-term solution is to download the media to able to re-upload it at a later time. You may also have some "storage" channel where you forward everything so you can refetch and resend the media from there.